# Zend > Access library from a module controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have been using a modular structure for my zend framework application.

This is my sample project hierarchy:

- application

  - modules

    - v1

      - controllers

        - SampleController.php
      - models
      - views
      - configs

        - module.ini
  - configs

    - application.xml
- library

  - My

    - Math

      - File.php

I want to access the library class file: "File.php" inside my module controller: "SampleController.php".

I tried instantiating it from my controller like this:

```
$sample = new My_Math_File();
```

But i got an error like this:

> Fatal error: Class 'My_Math_File' not
>   found in
>   E:\zend\Apache2\htdocs\project\application\modules\v1\controllers\SampleController.php

Could not undserstand how to access the library resources from my module controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure to add `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My"`
to your application.ini 
and  99% this would solve it

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I included: **autoloaderNamespaces.my = "My_"** in my application.ini and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Just curious to know... how can i have a separate database config for each of my modules? I tried the code here, but it did not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190911/problem-with-zend-module-specific-configuration/5219294#5219294

Comment: to be honest i am fan of doctrine + ZF but if you want to stick with zend db , you can take alook at http://www.amazium.com/blog/using-different-databases-with-zend-framework